# Swift check if array of anyObject have value

Tags: swift, anyobject

I have this array of anyObject that i use to read my JSON data downloaded.

```
datiArticolo!["anagrafica"]![linguaApp!]!!["img"]!!["path"]
```

The problem is that not always i have che ["img"] or/and ["path"] values.
how can i check if there are and if not do another action?

Comment: Ahhhh! All of those `!`. Why? Each one stands for "crash here".

Comment: swift tell me to put them

Comment: No, Xcode told you to put them in. Xcode is evil and it lied to you. It wants your app to crash so you will spend more time with it. Please spend time learning about optionals in Swift.

Comment: This data structure is completely broken (and I see how you got there, but we have to show you the way out). If you've arrived at two separate `!!` in the same expression, it is time to go back and rebuild your data structure. Do not store data in complicated, nested Dictionaries. Convert this to a struct of structs. Seriously, `!!` is madness. Multi-level dictionaries are madness. Dictionaries with fixed strings are sort-of madness (they shouldn't be used very often). It's time to redesign the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally want to check all forced unwraps to prevent crashes so you would continue this pattern up the chain. See more about [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

```
if let img = datiArticolo!["anagrafica"]![linguaApp!]!!["img"], path = img["path"] {
 // do something with `path`
}
```

Comment: I agree, that's why I said continue this pattern up the chain